# Eye bones are stuck on Eye Mesh when Posing other bones

Tags: mesh, rigging, pose-mode

I have an interesting issue. I am doing some tutorials and no matter what I do I cannot get past a specific area. I am doing Rigging and Posing, but when I go to move any part of the body my Eye Bone Rig is "Stuck" on my eyes. This is creating really odd issues as I cannot do any pose outside of move my eyes.

I can do some of the basic ones such as move arms, hands, and some minor lower body, but if I do anything that moves the entire top part of the body the eye mesh gets dragged along.

See examples below.

[image: headtilt]

Here is another one where the head is moving backwards

[image: backwards head]

I have been stuck on this for a while. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange, you probably will get a better answer if the question is about a specific issue, it's not clear how did you do the rig and parented the bones, it could be an issue with bone roll or parenting hierarchy, if you upload the .blend file and amend the link to your question, might help get the exact problem you're facing

Comment: Thanks George! I actually did have the .blender file, but later in the day found another use posted a similar question and that was the fix for mine too. I added it to my answer section below, but it wont let me accept it for 12 more hours!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another user posted the fix on a different thread. My Armature was at the "bottom" of the list causing the deformations. Once I moved this up it resolved my issue.

[image]